# Problem with VUE.js not recognize vue component with intellij

Tags: html, vue.js, web

I am writing because i have an issue using vue.js,

this is my index.html code:

```
  <!DOCTYPE html>
  <html lang="en">
  <head>
     <meta charset="UTF-8">
     <title>Title</title>
  </head>
 <body>
     <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue/dist/vue.js"></script>
     <script 
      src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"> 
     </script>

     <h1> Prova VUE  </h1>
     <div id="app">
         <p> Login:</p>
         <button v-on : click="getInfo">OK</button>
     </div>

<script>
    var app = new Vue({
        el: '#app',
        data: {
            cordocs: [],
            docenti: [],
            link : '/newProvaTweb/hello-servlet'
        },
        methods:{
            getInfo:function(){
                var self = this;
                    $.get(this.link,{
                        action: "initialization"
                    }, function (data) {
                        self.cordocs = data[0];
                    });
            }
        }
    });
</script>
```

I have included the script but, working with intellij doesn't recognize the vue component like this,

[image]

and it doesn't work. Someone know how to solve this problem?

Comment: What if you try with `@click`?

Comment: it doesn't work...

Comment: What language is set in your code editor?

Comment: how can I ceck this? I am using Intellij